# Issue with Offset Management in Debezium Embedded Connector for SQL Server When Applying Custom Filtering Logic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, debezium, cdc

I'm using Apache Camel, the Debezium embedded connector for SQL Server. I create my connector like this and then have a route that consumes it.

This is the connector:

```
public String buildDebeziumConnectorString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(SQLSERVER_CONNECTOR_NAME);
    sb.append("?databaseHostName=").append(properties.getDatabaseHostName())
      .append("&databasePort=").append(properties.getDatabasePort())
      .append("&databaseUser=").append(properties.getDatabaseUser())
      .append("&databasePassword=").append(properties.getDatabasePassword())
      .append("&databaseServerName=").append(properties.getDatabaseServerName())
      .append("&includeSchemaChanges=").append(properties.isIncludeSchemaChanges())
      .append("&databaseDbname=").append(properties.getDatabaseDbname())
      .append("&tableIncludeList=").append(properties.getTableWhitelist())
      .append("&offsetStorageFileName=").append(properties.getOffsetStorageFileName())
      .append("&databaseHistoryFileFilename=").append(properties.getDatabaseHistoryFileFilename())
//    .append("&additionalProperties.transforms=filterByCode")
//    .append("&additionalProperties.transforms.filterByCode.type=it.example.conf.FilterByCode")
;
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The idea is to apply my own filtering logic within a Java class. I must say that the filtering logic works and discards based on my business logic, but the problem is another one: that is, if I enable the filtering logic, it's like the offset gets lost, and it starts reading the same rows over again and reprocessing them. Whereas, when I don't use any filtering logic, it manages to keep the correct offset in memory.

What can we notice that is different in the offset.dat file

(Without filtering logic): offset.dat.....`{"commit_lsn":"00009cb5:0000018d:0001","snapshot":true,"snapshot_completed":true}`
It manages to complete the snapshot.

However, if I uncomment and apply the filtering logic
(with filtering logic): `"commit_lsn":"00009cb5:000001cd:0001","snapshot":true,"snapshot_completed":false}`
It does not manage to complete the snapshot.

What am I doing wrong, in your opinion?
Is there any property that I could add to the connector to always force the snapshot? Is there something I'm missing? How does a filtering logic so significantly change the behavior of the offset?

I could also add a filter later and implement it within the Apache Camel routes, but I would like to be able to use it within the Debezium connector itself.

As an additional note, this is the class I use to filter and process only with Code = 1, and the filter works.

```
@Slf4j
public class FilterByCode<R extends ConnectRecord<R>> implements Transformation<R> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public R apply(R recordRead) {
        if (recordRead.value() == null) {
            log.warn("Received null record value. Skipping this record.");
            return null;
        }

        Map<String, Object> recordValueMap = convertToMap(recordRead.value());

        if (recordValueMap == null || !recordValueMap.containsKey("after")) {
            log.warn("Invalid record map or missing 'after' key. Skipping this record.");
            return null;
        }

        Object afterObject = recordValueMap.get("after");
        Map<String, Object> afterMap;
        if (afterObject instanceof Struct) {
            afterMap = Utils.structToMap((Struct) afterObject);
        } else if (afterObject instanceof Map) {
            afterMap = (Map<String, Object>) afterObject;
        } else {
            log.warn("Unsupported 'after' value type: {}. Skipping this record.", afterObject.getClass().getName());
            return null;
        }

        if (afterMap.containsKey("Code") && "1.equals(afterMap.get("Code").toString())) {
            log.info("Record with Code=1 found and will be processed.");
            return recordRead;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, Object> convertToMap(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Struct) {
            return MyUtils.structToMap((Struct) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Map) {
            return (Map<String, Object>) value;
        } else {
            log.warn("Unsupported record value type: {}. Skipping this record.", value.getClass().getName());
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigDef config() {
        return new ConfigDef();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        log.info("Closing FilterByCode transformation.");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {
        log.info("Configuring FilterByCode transformation with settings: {}", map);
    }
}
```